# Пишу программу на Qt, не работает QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь разместить в диалоговом окне виджет с вкладками и виджет с кнопкой. Использую для этого `QGridLayout`:

```
ProcInfo::ProcInfo(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::ProcInfo)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Process info");
    tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
    generalTab = new QTableWidget();
    securityTab = new QTableWidget();
    tabWidget->addTab(generalTab, "General");
    tabWidget->addTab(securityTab, "Security");
    okButtonWidget = new QWidget();
    okButton = new QPushButton(okButtonWidget);
    okButton->setText(tr("OK"));
    mainWidget = new QWidget(this);
    mainLayout = new QGridLayout();
    mainLayout->addWidget(okButtonWidget, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(tabWidget, 1, 0);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    mainWidget->show();
    ...
    generalTab->setVisible(true);
    okButton->setVisible(true);
}
```

Заголовочный файл:

```
    class ProcInfo : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ProcInfo(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ProcInfo();

private slots:
    void on_okButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::ProcInfo *ui;
    QTabWidget *tabWidget;
    QTableWidget *generalTab;
    QTableWidget *securityTab;
    QStringList generalHeader;
    QGridLayout *mainLayout;
    QPushButton *okButton;
    QWidget *okButtonWidget;
    QWidget *mainWidget;
};
```

Проблема в том, что какие бы координаты в `addWidget` я не указывал, диалоговое окно выглядит одинаково и расположение виджетов в нём не соответствует действительности. Не понимаю, что я делаю не так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного сбоку от темы, но зачем же так мучиться? Проще же в дизайнере набросать

Comment: Возможно, но я так и не разобрался как создать в дизайнере, например, таблицу и потом заполнить её в коде. Не получается связать объект из дизайнера и из кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько моментов, которые, по моему мнению, следует исправить:

**1.** При создании виджетов вы не указываете родителей этих виджетов.

```
tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
generalTab = new QTableWidget();
securityTab = new QTableWidget();
...
```

Из-за отсутствия родительских элементов могут возникать различные ошибки (например, утечки памяти или некорректное отображение на форме). Поэтому родительские элементы лучше все таки задавать, причем задавать так, чтобы соблюдать семантику их вложенности.

---

**2.** При создании кнопки Вы создаёте отдельный виджет для неё.

```
okButtonWidget = new QWidget();
okButton = new QPushButton(okButtonWidget);
```

Этот виджет *избыточен*, т.к. кнопка сама по себе уже есть виджет.. Как по мне, лишнее место, где можно запутаться.

---

**3.** Вы создаете отдельный "родительский" виджет `mainWidget`.

```
mainWidget = new QWidget(this);
```

Этот виджет *избыточен*, т.к. при создании проекта по умолчанию создается `ui->centralWidget`, исключающий меню, тулбар и статусбар. Для распределения элементов в `layout` лучше использовать его (или иметь еще одно место потенциальной путанницы).

---

В итоге получаем более упрощенный код:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    tabWidget(new QTabWidget(this)),
    generalTab(new QTableWidget(tabWidget)),
    securityTab(new QTableWidget(tabWidget)),
    okButton(new QPushButton(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    tabWidget->addTab(generalTab, "General");
    tabWidget->addTab(securityTab, "Security");

    okButton->setText(tr("OK"));

    // указатель на layout можно не хранить, поэтому создаем его локально
    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout();

    mainLayout->addWidget(tabWidget, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(okButton, 1, 0);

    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

Получаем такое окно:

[image: скриншот приложения]

**P.S.** В конструкторе класса я выделил создание объектов в список инициализации, т.к. считаю, что такой подход более удобен для чтения кода (создание объектов в одном, ***логичном*** для этого месте).

Comment: `1)` не обязательно указывать родителей, это даже избыточно, т.к. при размещении объекта на виджет, тот уже получит родителя (через this в конструкторе или через компоновщик) `foo)` только у автора нет формы сгенерированной через дизайнера, поэтому `ui->centralWidget->setLayout(` может ввести в заблуждение :)

Comment: @gil9red, избыточно, когда знаешь, какие методы по дефолту устанавливают родителя, а какие нет (насколько я помню, не все методы это делают). Опыт подсказывает, что код иногда ведёт себя не так, как мы ожидаем (или даже не так, как написано в документации), и на начальных этапах обучения можно потратить кучу времени на поиск каких-то *неявных* тонкостей.

Comment: Ок, но по мне это указание родителя в конструктор каждого виджета, когда можно этого не делать делает код избыточным. Если у виджета нет родителя то он является окном, если он находится на другом виджете, то у него есть родитель. Все просто :) Если вы со мной не согласны, прошу не продолжать спор, а то во флуд превратится это

Comment: Думаю, это вопрос стиля из разряда "как лучше: `if (count) {...}` или `if (count != 0) {...}`". Спорить бессмысленно, у каждого программиста/проекта свой стиль :)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы создаете `mainWidget`?

У вас текущий виджет `ProcInfo` уже имеет возможность размещать в себе виджеты и поддерживает компоновщики (layouts)

Уберите `mainWindow` и просто используйте:

```
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Тогда компоновщик с таблицей и кнопкой разместятся на диалоге.

---

**PS.** в текущем виде проще использовать `QVBoxLayout`